# Item (Magento\Cms\Model\Block) with the same ID "353" already exists

Tags: error, blocks

This error appears when I'm trying to access one of the blocks. Any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have deleted this cms block with the block `id = 353`, and this block is used somewhere else.

You have to check your code, database where you have used this id then remove it.